# How to get hexadecimal characters from short string for colorcode

Tags: javascript, hex

I want hexadecimal color code from username string. for long user name it is working correctly but for short name its failing.
For freddie_steven it returns feddee, but for alex_steven it returns only aeee which is very short. How to fix this.

How to get valid hexadecimal color code from username to set a thumbnail background different with username.

```
#user-thumbnail{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

<div id='user-thumbnail'></div>

var username = 'freddie_steven';
var colorCode = '';

for(var i = 0; i<username.length; i++){
    if(username.charCodeAt(i) >= 97 && username.charCodeAt(i) <= 102)
        colorCode += username.charAt(i)
}

document.getElementById('user-thumbnail').style.background = '#' +colorCode.substr(0, 6);
```

Comment: What do you expect instead of `aeee`? Your code grabs the a, e, b, c, e and f characters from the name and puts them into a string.

Comment: well, we can't "fix" it if you we don't know what you're expecting.

Comment: I want to add characters to make valid hexadecimal color code

Comment: Do you want to get the same colour code for the same username? If so, can you generate a random colour and store this in a database, or do you need the colour code to be computed from the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick random character if the character does not match !

```js
var username = 'alex_steven';
var colorCode = '';

var validHex = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'f'
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * validHex.length);

for (var i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
  if (username.charCodeAt(i) >= 97 && username.charCodeAt(i) <= 102) {
    colorCode += username.charAt(i)
  } else {
    colorCode += validHex[randomNumber]
  }
}

console.log(colorCode.substr(0, 6));
```